# Java - how to implement threads on a process that waits for data

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I'm fairly new to multi threaded programming and I was hoping to get some insight into the best way to implement the following idea.

Right now my code works like this
[image: Current functionality]

It is singularly threaded, so in the time it takes to process each piece of data and write it to the database, new data comes in and gets queued up which is slowing things down too much.  I am running on a 4CPU server, but the current setup only uses 1.

I would like separate out the work done in the middle piece over the remaining 3 CPUs.  How would I best do this?  I thought that I could create a new thread for each new piece of data, but we are talking about over the course of a day hundreds of thousands of new threads.  From what I read, the overhead associated with that would be very large.  Memory is a concern for me so if the creation of all these threads eats too much memory I will be in trouble.  Is it true that a new thread will utilize a less busy CPU, or will it use the same one since it is the same JVM?

The processing and DB write for each new piece of data should not take more than a couple of seconds, if that.

I was also reading about thread pools, but the idea is a bit confusing to me and I can't find a great example.

I was thinking something like this
[image: Idea]

Please help a multi threaded newb out in coming up with a reasonable design!  Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: This question may be a little too open-ended for StackOverflow. You might want to cross-post at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/. Nice pictures though.

Comment: I would take the time to read through [Java Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html), paying special attention to the section on [Executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html). While I agree with Duncan, +1 for a well thought out question

Comment: I think your last image basically nails it. You will however probably want to pass your processed data to other threads that write them to the database to be able to adjust the number of threads for the processing step and writing step sepearetely.

Comment: Sounds like a problem that can be solved by using producers and consumers. Furthermore, you might want to use some kind of connection-pool to the database to correctly handle the connection to the database. Never work with threads directly though, sometimes it is better to execute something within the same thread; creating threads is relatively expensive.

Comment: @Duncan - Thank you, I haven't seen the programmers stackexchange before.  Will post there.  

Kristoffer It may make sense to separate out the database piece, but it basically leads me to the same question of how can I have a thread wait for some action.  

MadProgrammer - I will look into the Executors class, perhaps this is what I need

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The more important point would be, how many threads are working in parallel (in thus potentially killing a machine). If you are creating one Thread object after another, it could be done more efficiently, but in general the cost for that is (probably) negligible (as Michal pointed out). Leaving that aside (and assuming you want to learn about multi-threading), your design sounds reasonable enough already. Now go have a look what [`java.util.concurrent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) can provide you with respect on tools to achieve it:

- `ExecutorService`: Would be the best choice. Create a fixed thread pool of `n` worker threads and then, for each incoming thread, post one `Runnable` doing your processing and storing all the data to the database.

  ```
  public class DataProcessor {
      final ExecutorService workerThreadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

      public void onNewDataFromTheOutsideWorld(Data d) { 
         workerThreadPool.execute(new ProcessingAndStoreToDBRunnable(d));
      }

      public void onShutdown() { 
         workerThreadPool.shutdown();
      }
  }
  ```

  The `ExecutorService` will make sure that only the fixed numbers of workers are actually running in parallel,
- Own queue-ing mechanism: When it comes to jobs which have different priorities, you might want to implement your own working mechanism. Note that this is much more complicated, and you should probably stick to the `ExecutorService` solution if possible.

  The basic idea is to have a `BlockingQueue` to which data is added and start `n` worker threads you read from the queue the jobs. The trick is, the queue will block if there are no jobs (thus sending the threads to sleep), if there are more than `n` jobs, the jobs are stored in the queue until a processing thread is available.

  ```
  public class DataProcessor {
      final BlockingQueue<Data> queue = new BlockingQueue<Data>();

      public void onInit() {
         for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
             new Thread(new WorkerRunnable(queue)).start();
      }

      public void onNewDataFromTheOutsideWorld(Data d) { 
         queue.add(d);
      }
  }

  public class WorkerRunnable implements Runnable {
      public void run() { 
         while (true) {
             Data d = queue.take();
             processData(d);
         }
      }
   }
  ```

  As I said, this is much more complicated to realize as I still haven't touched issues like

  - Stopping the worker threads
  - Making sure to handle exceptions and then return on to processing
  - etc.

These are just basic (yet very powerful) tools in a multi-threading environment. If you need more advanced tools, checkout the Guava library, for example with their wonderful concept of a [`ListenableFuture`](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained) (which you should use if you need the result of a worker thread.)

You then would have a rather basic design, from where you can add some more sophisticated processing steps as already pointed out in your comments. Also it was pointed out, that it then turn in a rather broad question ;)

Comment: Please avoid doing the while (true) bit. It's one of the worst performance offenders. It's actually a textbook case. The issue here is that if there is a delay when data is coming from the outside world, this does not mean that the thread will do nothing. It will actually consume whatever cpu cycles the OS has alloted, to only check if "while(true)" actually is true...and since it always is, it just wastes cycles, thus, if you do this, you can even get worse performance.

The classic apporach to solve this is to use wait and notify, or in this case notifyAll.

Comment: Cont'd... So basically you do something like "if (!queue.isEmpty()) queue.take()" and then "else wait()" This way, if you want an object form the queue and it's empty, the thread just goes to sleep, indefinetely. More precisely, until another thread does a notify or notifyAll. In this case, the object that puts the data into the queue would do "queue.put(data); notifyAll();" this prevents the situation mentioned above, known as "busy waiting". So, pretty please, avoid this "while(true)" as the plague!. You can confirm this in any CS book, and you will see a much better explanation.

Comment: I appreciate you comment, but `take()` will `wait()` until a new item is available in the queue. The `while(true)` (and I agree with you on this, avoid it in general!) is here to illustrate that the worker thread must after finishing processing one message from the queue re-start working on the queue.

Comment: @Acapulco I don't see why you think the `while(true)` is an issue: `queue.take();` is a blocking call... And the suggested approach in this answer is much better than using wait/notify as you propose.

Comment: @Stephan putting the `queue.take()` in a `while(true)` is absolutely fine. It is not going to use any CPU cycles until the queue is non empty and it can be interrupted. It is even used as an example in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html). (+1 by the way)

Comment: Thank you, I don't think there would be too many threads in parallel, maybe 50 maximum as I mentioned to Michael.  With the Executor/threadpool option, how does it work?  I allocate 5 threads and the OS just reuses the threads? So if I allocate 5 and I have 10 new pieces of data, would it be that each thread is responsible for about 2, and each one thread fully completes one task before starting the other?

Comment: @Stephan. Ahh, my mistake. I just kinda have an itch for when I see while(true)'s, especially when talking about threads. In any case, maybe it's good to clarify this point anyway, as the question seems to imply little thread knowledge, and it seems way too easy for the asker to just replace that queue.take() and replace ir with some other code and expect the same behavior. However, it's always good to get corrected and learning something. +1 for the discussion :)

Comment: @Marianna Exactly. The `ExecutorService` will make sure there are only running `n` threads in parallel. All exceeding tasks are queued up and being processed one after the other. How many threads are a good number to run in parallel depends on the number of CPUs and whether they are more I/O bound or calculating tasks. E.g. if one processing takes one CPU for 30 seconds to 100% (no I/O), it does not make sense to let more threads run than available CPUs. On the other hand, having threads only depending on I/O you can probably run more.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should consider how important performance is in this application and what kind of traffic you need to handle. If you do not care much about adding a latency of 0.1 ms to each request (which I think you don't if you say each request takes several seconds), than creating a new thread will not be a noticeable cost. Note that your threads should end their life after they're done with their work, so you won't have hundreds of thousands of threads at the same time - they will be started and ended over time. If you get "a few hundred thousand" requests per day, this is just several requests per second (assuming they are split out evenly). With such parameters, your average number of active requests will be on the order of a few dozen (about 10 per second times several seconds per request ~= a few dozen requests live at any moment). This is more than the number of cores on your machine, but should be handled without any issues - if these threads communicate with the DB, they will spend most of their time waiting for the communication link. While having a separate thread for each request may not be the best design in general, it will probably be easier to implement than something fancy as learning about Futures and Executors.

So both solutions have their merits - Futures for better design and possibly better resource usage (though this may depend on how well you schedule them) and thread per request to get something working fast (and be easily able to understand what is going on inside the system). If you are now only learning concurrency, I would actually recommend you do it the less elegant way first in order to understand what the system needs to do behind the scenes. Then, when you are familiar with that "manual" scheduling approach, you can go to the higher level of abstraction, learn Futures et al, and refactor your code. That second version will probably be much better than the code you will be able to write if you start with Futures right away.

Comment: So then is it a fair assumption that by using more than one thread, the OS will automatically delegate the work to the least busy CPU?  Thank you for your input.  You are correct that the threads will be short lived, so I may only have 50 at most active at one time which doesn't seem terrible.  I don't care too much about a 100 ms latency, so long as it stays that way.  Right now the latency is out of control because over the course of the day it creeps up and up until it is at the level of minutes.

Comment: @Marianna Normally the OS is quite good at scheduling, so in your setup I think it can handle 50 or 100 threads on 4 cores without much trouble. These threads will spend most time waiting for the database, not performing computation, so it's quite safe to have many of them. I would actually be more worried if the DB can handle that many parallel requests. BTW the latency I'm talking about is on the order of 0.1 ms, not 100 ms.